# SQL Server Management Studio as MMC Snap-In

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms, mmc

Is there any MMC snap-in for the SQL Server Management Studio 2008/2012 ?

I know that there is a snap-in for the SQL Server Configuration Manager, but that is not what I need.

I want to make queries to the SQL server directly through MMC and manage my databases and tables.
The SQL server is not local installed.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately you have to access the Management Studio separately.

I'm 99% sure, however I'd love to be wrong, this would be great for use with 2012.

Comment: mhhh, that would be a great completion for managing a webserver :(
Do you know if it even not integrated on the SQL 2012 series ?

Comment: @Solaflex unfortunately not! Just the config manager as you mentioned before :(